# Android .apk installation - Application not installed

Tags: android, apk

I've installed the appropriate .apk file, however when trying to install it the app it gives me the error 'Application not installed'. I've tried to put a simple Hello World .apk file on there and I receive the same message.

Here's what I have tried:
1. Adding the following to Application Manifest

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

2.  I have installed multiple File Managers including Astro, Android File Manager and ES File Explorer
3.  I have enabled all of the correct settings on the Sony Xperia U (running Android 2.3.7)
4.  Tried installation whilst the device is plugged in, and whilst it isn't

I'm using a **Unsigned** Android Application. Everything runs accordingly on the Eclipse emulator

Logcat is reporting the following:

[image]

This is displayed even when my device is connected via USB.

Comment: "I'm using a Unsigned Android Application" -- you cannot install or run unsigned apps. "Everything runs accordingly on the Eclipse emulator" -- you are not running an unsigned app via Eclipse, either. All apps are signed by default (whether with the debug signing key or a production signing key). "Logcat is reporting the following" -- your URL for the image is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Locate your `myapp.apk` file on your hard drive:

Install it via command line:

```
C:\android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe install myapp.apk
```

List of connected devices:

```
adb devices
```

Connecting a device (if its number is 5554):

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:5554
```

Restarting ADB:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Your APK is having an expired or mis-configured certificate.

You need to resign the apk using the following tools.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kellinwood.zipsigner2&hl=en

or

https://code.google.com/p/apk-signer/

Sign the APK with output filename as HelloWorld_signed.apk

Then go to my files you Will see your signed apk.

Install HelloWorld_signed.apk.

The app Will install successfully..

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a constraint of permission to prevent you to do so, I have worked around and find a simple solution for my Sony Xperia 1, OS version 5.1.1

Go through these steps:

1. Settings
2. Apps
3. Download Tab
4. Scroll down to find your app there
5. Press the menu and select **Uninstall for all users**